# Exclude directory from intellij inspection, but not exclude from autocomplete

Tags: java, css, twitter-bootstrap, intellij-idea, static-analysis

As far as I know, the only way to exclude a directory is to mark it as excluded in project structure. However, this would make IntelliJ totally ignore the directory. Thus it will not appear in autocomplete options.

I do not want this. I want exclusion from inspections but inclusion in everything else. Is this possible?

I'm using Intellij 12.0.2. And, it's actually the bootstrap css and js failing the inspection.

Comment: You can set the default "Inspection Scope" to be a "Custom Scope"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As suggested by [Peter Lawrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57695/peter-lawrey), the proper solution would be to use the [custom inspection scope](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/scopes.html) that excludes the directories where you don't want the inspections to be run.

Comment: I have modified the scope, but it is not applied. Why? I have even recreated the cache & restarted the application.

Comment: @JFFIGK after scope created: inspections -> select some inspections, select scope and change them

Answer (score 14):

With IntelliJ 15, you can mark the directory as `Generated Sources Root`. This skips the inspections but auto-complete will still work.

1. Right click on the desired directory
2. Select `Mark Directory As`/`Generated Sources Root`

NB: It seems, that you cannot select this type in the `Project Structure` dialogue, only via the right click.

Answer (score 8):

There is man in a hat in status bar. Click on it and select inspection level.

[image]

Also, if you have many files you want to supress inspection, then go to `.idea` and edit `workspace.xml`, find `<component name="HighlightingSettingsPerFile">` and add line like this:

```
<setting file="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/src/main/config/config.xml" root0="SKIP_HIGHLIGHTING" />
```

I find it simplier than editing inspection levels.

Comment: that doesn't answer the question

Comment: As soon as I start IDEA, I'll provide a screenshot. Also, I'll mention how to do it by modifying XML file.

Comment: don't worry I need to define my own custom scope as commented