# Huge Axis2 stubs are not identified as java class files in intelliJ IDEA 12

Tags: jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, apache-axis

We have a Java EE application with

- Java 6,
- JSF 1.2,
- Icefaces 1.8.2,
- Axis 1.4.1
- on Eclipse 3.7

and want to upgrade our development pipeline and product to

- Java 7
- JSF 2,
- Icefaces 3.3.0
- Axis 1.4.1 (for now, upgrade later to current stable)
- on Maven 4 and IntelliJ IDEA 12.

Since we do not want to rebuild our webservice stubs in Axis2 1.6.2 for now, we remained on Version 1.4.1.

Our problem is that we have some huge webservice stubs which are around 70.000 LOC. All classes within these stubs cannot be found by other java classes even if the imports and classpaths are set right.

The stubs' compilation passes without any errors and the class files are created correct however the source files are not identified as classes but java files (=different icons in project navigator).

What we have tried so far:

- Increase the compiler's memory to 2048MB (Settings -> Compiler -> Java Compiler)
- Recreate the webservice stub with wsdl2code
- Turn off all IntelliJ IDEA inspections

Have you any idea why IntelliJ does not recognize the stubs as expected? Is there a file size limit?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please [check this document](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23395793):

`IDE_HOME\bin\idea.properties`:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Maximum file size (kilobytes) IDE should provide code assistance for.
# The larger file is the slower its editor works and higher overall system memory requirements are
# if code assistance is enabled. Remove this property or set to very large number if you need
# code assistance for any files available regardless their size.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.max.intellisense.filesize=2500
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is indeed the answer.  
EDIT: Since this results in a much higher memory consumption I followed the suggestion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437647/exclude-directory-from-intellij-inspection-but-not-exclude-from-autocomplete) and defined a custom inspection scope.

Answer (score 3):

Use option -u with wsdl2java utility, it will create multiple class files and thus should resolve your issue

source:
[Axis2 WSDL2java is generating only 2 java classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461291/axis2-wsdl2java-is-generating-only-2-java-classes)